# Use puts() to overwrite new value on the location pointed by a pointer

Tags: c

I hope to get some advice. I thank you so much.

```
char *p = "abc";
printf("Value at the location the pointer points to = %s\n", p);
printf("The location where the pointer points to = %d\n", p);
printf("The location of the pointer = %d\n", &p);
char s[] = "Hello";
printf("Vi tri cua s = %d\n", &s);
gets(s);  //we must enter less than 5 characters, because we have s[5]
puts(s);
printf("The new value at the location the pointer points to:\n");
gets(p);  //This function cause problem, while the function gets(s) does not
puts(p);
```

Comment: you don't declare `s` as `char s[24]` so the comment in your code is wrong - it gets declared as big enough to hold the string `"Hello"`

Comment: Yes, you right, I have edited the code - changing 24 into 5.

Comment: @loveCLoveC `s` actually is of type `char[6]`.

Comment: "*... because we have s[5]*", no, you have `s` be a `char[6]`. Mind the `0`-terminator.

Answer (score 0):

`"abc"` is a literal and is write-protected (read-only). Hence you can't read into it.

`char s[] = "Hello";` creates an array and copies the literal string into it. The resulting array is not a literal, hence can be modified.

Comment: "is write-protected (read-only)" + "with the vast majority of compilers". (I have not run into any where it isn't, but supposedly there is such an animal out in the wild)